Movie where a city is being divided by a huge wall
I watched a movie when I was much younger and I would like to rewatch it, but I don't remember much.
I think the city was divided by the huge wall to protect the inside from the outside world. The inside was much more safe, rich and all the other things than the outside world, but there was some group from the outside that managed to get to the inside and from some skyscraper or some high building, I think they managed to destroy the wall by some cannon or something like that.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately what year was this?

Colony tv series perhaps 2016 - 2018

Details are important, this is a common feature of multiple flicks. There is French movie, fairly recent, where the underclass live outside but can get highly sought-after jobs inside the wall. There is a zombie flick with Dennis Hopper that sort of has a wall. I think the theme is ancient given that walled-cities is a real thing. Even castles were sort of like walled cities.

This is Maze Runner: The Death Cure (2018), the third instalment in the Maze Runner film series.

Young hero Thomas embarks on a mission to find a cure for a deadly disease known as "The Flare".

The plot involves the main characters trying to reach WCKD's headquarters (a skyscraper) in the Last City, which is surrounded by a huge wall separating the wealthy residents within from the post-apocalyptic slums without. The top of the wall is lined with large gun turrets to fend off anyone trying to force their way in.
The main characters manage to sneak in with help from the inside, but other forces subsequently breach the wall using explosives.




You are crazy :D thanks a lot this is it

@Filip - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

And then everyone gets The Flare.  Way to go, Thomas!!

Apparently the passing of time really is becoming more and more relative, as a movie from "when I was much younger" turns out being from 2018 ... in a few years, a question for "a really old show" will probably refer to something broadcast a fortnight before :-)

@lfurini There has been no visible response from OP so far, so we don't know whether this is the correct answer.

@Mast - The OP left a comment (which my own previous comment was a response to) stating "this is it." That comment has since been deleted, but I've notified the mods and asked them to restore it.
